# MUI tabs error on conditionaly showing a tab

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I have a 4 tabs and showing it conditionaly. I also have a useState("1") as a tabs.value.
When first element is hiding I'm getting the error:
MUI: The `value` provided to the Tabs component is invalid.
None of the Tabs' children match with "1".
You can provide one of the following values: 2, 3.

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea to share a picture of your code here. 
Please try reading [How to ask in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question in order to help others help you easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the same validation to each TabPanel, It should exist one tab per panel